# Unable To Update Posts in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a bloglike application and am working on updating posts when editing.

I use a partial called _post_form to edit posts:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new post..." %>
</div>
<div id="post_button">
<%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Relevant code from my posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

def update
  redirect_to @post
end

def find_note
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

When I click the "Post" button it will redirect me to the correct post however it will not actually update it with the new text I enter into the form. I feel like there is something basic I'm missing but I'm not sure what it is.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating anything in your controller, you are just redirecting the user to the `post` view.

First get the new values of `post`:

```
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
  end
```

And then update it before redirecting:

```
def update
  @post.update(post_params)
  redirect_to @post
end
```

Putting it all together, your controller should look something like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_note, only: [:show, :edit, :update]

  def update
    @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to @post
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
  end

  def find_note
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, I understand it a lot better now!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing model `update` call in `PostsController#update` action which is why your post record isn't getting updated. Update the post record before redirecting in `PostsController#update` action

```
def update
  @post.update(post_params) ## <- add this
  redirect_to @post
end
```

NOTE: assuming you are using Rails version >= 4 and are whitelisting attributes(strong parameters) in `post_params`.